# Rapid Spanning Tree Protocol - RSTP Bridge Id isn't RSTP-Priority + Ethernet-MAC

Tags: spanning-tree, wireshark

what is the difference between the eth.src Address and the Bridge-System-Id? Sometimes they are the same but mostly not. Attached you will find a screenshot where they are the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eth.src is the media access control address (MAC address) of the device which is a unique identifier assigned to network interfaces for communications at the data link layer of a network segment.

In terms of STP Bridge system identifier (BID) is a unique identifier composed by priority and MAC address.

So depending on the priority(32768 is the default value) which is in configured in increments of 4096 you will have different values showing on the BID.

**EDIT HERE**

In regards to your comment concern:

> as you see in the screenshot the priority isn't zero but the mac and
>   bridge-id are the same. How could that be if you are correct?

Highlight Bridge Identifier: 32768 / 0 / 00:17:ef:74:62:00 to check hex.

In the hex values you look for your MAC and in front of that you would see the 2byte for the decimal value of 32768 (32768+0).

So something like:   80 00 00 17 ef 74 62 00

Comment: as you see in the screenshot the priority isn't zero but the mac and bridge-id are the same. How could that be if you are correct?

Comment: @thomas please check edited answer

Comment: Your comment is correct, but there is also a case where this do not work. I added a screenshot of an example where it do not match.

Comment: @thomas first case is STP and the device itself is root bridge, second case is RSTP and device is not root bridge, my understanding per the scope of the title on the question it was about STP and not RSTP correct?

Comment: Some bridges use the source MAC from their interface towards the link in question but the bridge ID is always (built) the same for a specific device, regardless of interface.

Comment: The screenshots are from RSTP. I will correct the title

Comment: @Zac67 This means the ports have an own mac address?

Comment: @thomas +1 to Zac67, small reference  https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/77420

Comment: @thomas It can be port-specific but most often the MAC is module or subsystem-specific (internal or replaceable).

Comment: @thomas, Cisco switch interfaces, even virtual interfaces (SVIs), have a MAC address. "_MAC addresses used for Spanning Tree calculations are stored in an EEPROM present in the Supervisor module. Regardless of the types of line modules installed, the Layer 2 MAC addresses for VLANs do not change unless you replace the Supervisor module. If you do replace the Supervisor module, the Layer 2 MAC addresses of all VLANs change to those specified in the address allocator on the new Supervisor module. In the fixed configuration Catalyst switches, MAC addresses for VLANs cannot be changed._"